# How to Retarget Solution that we use in Visual Studio using command line? Is there a specific command line script that we can run to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, msbuild, uwp-xaml, react-native-windows

I get this error when i try to run the build for React Native Windows
`Error : Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformMinVersion >= 10.0.17763.0 (current project is 16299) getting this error when building react native windows`.
But I am able to fix this issue by retargeting solution from Visual Studio UI. This will update all my files including the ones in my node modules as well.
But i want to try this through command line so that i can use it in my CI/CD

i tried this script but its giving me error: `msbuild windows\BopisPlus\BopisPlus.vcxproj /p:WindowsTargetPlatformVersion=10.0.17763.0` 
error: error MSB4184 The expression "[MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove('', node_modules\react-native-windows\package.json)" cannot be evaluated. The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)
But running retarget from Visual studio works fine without any errors

Comment: The file extension of your project file, `.vcxproj`,  indicates the project is a C++ project. Is a [React Native for Windows app](https://microsoft.github.io/react-native-windows/docs/native-code) in C++? When you say you are retargeting the solution from the Visual Studio UI, can you explain what steps are you taking to do that?

Comment: React native is written in javascript and the framework converts the code into windows platform native code. Therefore the configuration files for native code are like that of C++.

Comment: What i do generally in Visual studio to retarget solution is Open Visual Studio=> Open project/solution => right click project solution=> click retarget solution=> in pop up window , provide the required windows sdk version. Please refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBF4y-jh3AA. Right now , i found a work around to do this by running a powershell script to manually find and check the MinTargetPlatformversion in all files and change it to the desired one.

Comment: BTW The `/p` switch to MSBuild sets the value of a property for that run. It doesn't change the 'source' files.